# Show hidden property in certain routes (api_token)

Tags: laravel, laravel-5.5

I am using Laravel 5.5.13. I have given my user migration a api_token field by doing:

```
php artisan make:migration --table=users adds_api_token_to_users_table
```

And then implementing the migration like this:

```
public function up()
{
    Schema::table('users', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->string('api_token', 60)->unique()->nullable();
    });
}

public function down()
{
    Schema::table('users', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->dropColumn(['api_token']);
    });
}
```

I want this "api_token" field to only show for certain endpoints, and be hidden on the rest. If in my User.php model if I add to `protected $hidden = []` array then it is hiding in all. I was needing this "api_token" field to show in my register and login endpoints which are in my LoginController.php:

```
public function login(Request $request)
{
    $this->validateLogin($request);

    if ($this->attemptLogin($request)) {
        $user = $this->guard()->user()->load('pets');
        $user->generateToken();

        return $user;
    }

    return $this->sendFailedLoginResponse($request);
}
```

And in my RegisterController.php

```
protected function registered(Request $request, $user)
{
    $user->generateToken();

    return response()->json($user, 201);
}
```

Is it possible to show a hidden field in these endpoints?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you would like to make some typically hidden attributes visible on a given model instance, you may use the  `makeVisible()` method.
https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/eloquent-serialization